# Working with TableController in Azure Mobile Apps / Services

Tags: rest, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to understand how to work with `TableController` in Azure Mobile Apps. Here's the sample `TodoItemController`:

```
    public class TodoItemController : TableController<TodoItem>
    {
        protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
        {
            base.Initialize(controllerContext);
            MobileServiceContext context = new MobileServiceContext();
            DomainManager = new EntityDomainManager<TodoItem>(context, Request, Services);
        }

        // GET tables/TodoItem
        public IQueryable<TodoItem> GetAllTodoItems()
        {
            return Query();
        }

        // GET tables/TodoItem/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
        public SingleResult<TodoItem> GetTodoItem(string id)
        {
            return Lookup(id);
        }

        // PATCH tables/TodoItem/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
        public Task<TodoItem> PatchTodoItem(string id, Delta<TodoItem> patch)
        {
            return UpdateAsync(id, patch);
        }

        // POST tables/TodoItem
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostTodoItem(TodoItem item)
        {
            TodoItem current = await InsertAsync(item);
            return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
        }

        // DELETE tables/TodoItem/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
        public Task DeleteTodoItem(string id)
        {
            return DeleteAsync(id);
        }
    }
```

- Ideally, I'd like to avoid passing around whole models like `TodoItem` to reduce incoming/outgoing bandwidth and limit clients to only what they should care about. If I were to do that, how would offline sync and client-side SDKs be affected?
- Is `TableController` intended for simple CRUD operations as suggested above? Any examples out on the Internet with complex queries?

Comment: what do you use for client-side ? windows store app ? mobile app ? as far as i know, azure sqlitestore will always push/pull entire entity

Answer (score 2):

The Mobile Apps TableController is the basis for an OData based CRUD interface.  You will always transmit an entire model (which is based on an EntityData model, so it has four additional fields - version, createdAt, updatedAt and deleted) to the client.  However, the client can use an OData search to get a specific set of entities.  For more information on OData, check out http://www.odata.org/

In the specific case of Offline Sync and using the Mobile Apps SDK for clients, the client SDK will issue a GET but limit the results to the last update time (which will be zero for the first request and hence will get everything).  It will then push up the changes from the client.  In certain cases (where the version does not match), it will have to do conflict resolution.  Check out "How Offline Sync Works" in their documentation: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-offline-data-sync-preview/

Comment: Also, here's a sample for Azure Mobile Services that shows how to map complex models to simpler Data Transfer Objects (DTOs) using Automapper: https://github.com/paulbatum/fieldEngineerLite/. We're in the process of retargeting the sample to work with the Mobile Apps SDK, but the basic setup is very similar. The client SDKs then work with this simplified model. This same sample also shows how you can add additional server-side querying, which can be as complex as you'd like.

Comment: @lindydonna-msft Has the sample been retargeted yet?  I'm currently interested in what the `JobController .GetAllJobs` method would look like.